# Drupal removes a page from menu links after page edit

Tags: drupal

This might be a really simple thing but i was unable to find an answer to it. The issue is this:

I'm using Drupal 7, updated from Drupal 6. I have main menu to which i've assigned some pages. Whenever i edit one of those pages Drupal, for some reason, removes it from the menu links. Anyone ever had the same problem or would anyone have any ideas as to why it behaves this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only needed to enable it from the settings - 'Provide a menu link'.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's try to rule some things out.  You said that you assigned this menu to some pages.  If you are viewing the page in view mode, then click edit, then save, you will be taken back to the view of that node.  If you are viewing all of your content in the admin, then click edit by the node, then click save, you will be taken back to the list of content in the admin.  Take a look where you assigned this menu to, AND/OR where you did not assign it to. Make sure you are not looking at a page where the menu was not assigned to.